# Can TeamCity get source code from a network attached server?

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, teamcity

I keep all of my source code in a repo which lives on a Network Attached Server. I have just started playing around with continuous integration with TeamCity and I want it to be able to grab the code from the NAS. When I try to setup the VSC connection it fails and gives a warning that TeamCity cannot access mapped network drives. Is there any simple way of getting around this? How do most people do it?

Answer (score 2):

Have TeamCity check out your code from the repository, not the network drive, usually over http.  Pretty much the same way as when developer are working with the repository.

http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Configuring+VCS+Settings